# regex to extract nested patterns in parentheses and square brackets

Tags: python, regex

I have

`(LEFT-WALL)(who)(is.v)(Obama)(,)(I.p)(love.v)(his)(speech.s)(RIGHT-WALL)`

sort of pattern, which I split out and get each parenthesis item in list. my regex works fine, but for nested text like (Ob(am)a)

Example:

```
post_script_word_str = '(LEFT-WALL)(who)(is.v)(Obama)(,)(I.p)(love.v)(his)(speech.s)(RIGHT-WALL)'
post_script_word_list = re.compile(r'\(([^\)\(]*)\)').split(post_script_word_str)
print post_script_word_list

post_script_link_str = '[0 12 4 (RW)][0 7 3 (Xx)][0 1 0 (Wd)][1 2 0 (Ss)][2 6 2 (Ost)][3 6 1 (Ds)][3 4 0 (La)][5 6 0 (AN)][7 8 0 (Wq)][8 9 0 (EAh)][9 10 0 (AF)][10 11 0 (SIs)]'
post_script_link_str = re.compile(r'\[([^\]\[]*)\]').split(post_script_link_str)
print post_script_link_str
```

result:

```
    ['', 'LEFT-WALL', '', 'who', '', 'is.v', 'Obama', ',', '', 'I.p', '', 'love.v', '', 'his', '', 'speech.s', '', 'RIGHT-WALL', '']

['', '0 12 4 (RW)', '', '0 7 3 (Xx)', '', '0 1 0 (Wd)', '', '1 2 0 (Ss)', '', '2 6 2 (Ost)', '', '3 6 1 (Ds)', '', '3 4 0 (La)', '', '5 6 0 (AN)', '', '7 8 0 (Wq)', '', '8 9 0 (EAh)', '', '9 10 0 (AF)', '', '10 11 0 (SIs)', '']
```

but for input like `(Ob(am)a)` or `[0 [1]2 4 (RW)]` it fails. I expect same result as above but it gives

```
['', 'LEFT-WALL', '', 'who', '', 'is.v', '(Ob', 'am', 'a)', ',', '', 'I.p', '', 'love.v', '', 'his', '', 'speech.s', '', 'RIGHT-WALL', '']

['[0 ', '1', '2 4 (RW)]', '0 7 3 (Xx)', '', '0 1 0 (Wd)', '', '1 2 0 (Ss)', '', '2 6 2 (Ost)', '', '3 6 1 (Ds)', '', '3 4 0 (La)', '', '5 6 0 (AN)', '', '7 8 0 (Wq)', '', '8 9 0 (EAh)', '', '9 10 0 (AF)', '', '10 11 0 (SIs)', '']
```

any suggestion?

Updated input :

```
post_script_link_str = '[0 [1]2 4 (RW)][0 7 3 (Xx)][0 1 0 (Wd)][1 2 0 (Ss)][2 6 2 (Ost)][3 6 1 (Ds)][3 4 0 (La)][5 6 0 (AN)][7 8 0 (Wq)][8 9 0 (EAh)][9 10 0 (AF)][10 11 0 (SIs)]'
```

result :

```
['[0 ', '1', '2 4 (RW)]', '0 7 3 (Xx)', '', '0 1 0 (Wd)', '', '1 2 0 (Ss)', '', '2 6 2 (Ost)', '', '3 6 1 (Ds)', '', '3 4 0 (La)', '', '5 6 0 (AN)', '', '7 8 0 (Wq)', '', '8 9 0 (EAh)', '', '9 10 0 (AF)', '', '10 11 0 (SIs)', '']
```

Comment: are you comfortable with regex module?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: hey friend, I am comfortable with regex. is regex module is same ?

Comment: `re` is a builtin module but `regex` is an external module. You need to install that module manually.

Comment: could you provide an example which replicates this `[0 [1]2 4 (RW)]` ? did you want to deal with `(Ob(am)a)` also? Post an example which replicate both along with an expected output.

Comment: @AvinashRaj round and square brackate both are different case. I added example for both. Let me know if you need any further details please

Comment: i didn't find `[0 [1]2 4 (RW)]` substring in your input.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: apologize for inconvenience, please check edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74610/discussion-between-nlper-and-avinash-raj).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The re module is unable to deal with nested structures. You need to use the [new regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) that has the recursion feature. As an aside, I think that the `findall` method is more appropriate for this job:

```
regex.findall(r'\[([^][]*+(?:(?R)[^][]*)*+)]', post_script_link_str)
```

You obtain:

```
['0 [1]2 4 (RW)', '0 7 3 (Xx)', '0 1 0 (Wd)', '1 2 0 (Ss)', '2 6 2 (Ost)', '3 6 1 (Ds)', '3 4 0 (La)', '5 6 0 (AN)', '7 8 0 (Wq)', '8 9 0 (EAh)', '9 10 0 (AF)', '10 11 0 (SIs)']
```

All you need now is to map the list to remove square brackets.

pattern details:

`(?R)` allows the recursion since it is an alias for the whole pattern.

`*+` is a possessive quantifier. It's the same than `*` but doesn't allow the regex engine to backtrack. It is used here to prevent a catastrophic backtracking if unfortunately brackets are not balanced.

Comment: thanks dear, I tried this `re.compile(r'\[([^][]*+(?:(?R)[^][]*)*+)]').split(post_script_word_str)` which gives `
error: multiple repeat`

Comment: @niper: instead of copy/paste the first pattern you see in a post, take the time to read it in the same way I have take the time to write it. Thanks.